# Can I change the <td> background if a field result is great or equal to another field?

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, background-color, tablesorter

I am displaying mySQL in an html table.

I would like to change the TD background color of $qty to red `IF $qty >= $max  or  $qty =< $min`.

Is there a simple a way to do this with jQuery or PHP?

I simplified my table and PHP for my example:

```
<table id="tablesorter-demo">
<tr><td>'.$min.'</td><td>'.$max.'</td><td>'.$qty.'</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, with an `if else` statement in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var min = $('table tr td:eq(0)').text();
var max = $('table tr td:eq(1)').text();
var qty = $('table tr td:eq(2)').text();

if (qty >= max || qty <= min ) {
   $('table tr td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vUFS/3/

Comment: I'm getting an error at line if (qty >= max || qty =< min ) {

Comment: Appreciate the try, but I can initiate in red backgrounds

Comment: $o .= '<tr><td>'.$type.'</td><td>'.$part_no.'</td><td>'.$description.'</td><td>'.$artwork.' &nbsp; &nbsp;</td><td><a href="/data/hero/copies/'.$part_no.'.pdf" target="_blank">Link &nbsp;</a></td><td align=right>'.number_format($min).'</td><td align=right>'.number_format($max).'</td><td '.$style.' align=right>'.number_format($qty).'</td></tr>';}

Comment: Here is my php for the tr lines

Comment: I'm running into a conflict with the table-sorter script.  that has to be the problem.

Comment: Really appreciate your help.  I made this for myself to start figuring out the conflict:  http://jsfiddle.net/p7Ht5/

Comment: @Erik you are welcome, its better to use js codes in a separate file, i cannot see the outputted markup, try this js code with the markup. http://jsfiddle.net/7vUFS/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $class = (($qty >= $max) || ($qty <= min)) ? ' class="red"' : '';
?>

<tr><td>....</td><td<?php echo $class ?>><?php echo $qty ?></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you have your answer, but it would be better to just write a custom tablesorter widget that highlights the bad quantity table cells. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/4/) and the code:

```
$.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id : "qty",
    format: function(table){
        var i, $td, cur,
            c = table.config,
            cols = c.widgetQty,
            $tr = $(table).children('tbody').children('tr'),
            rows = $tr.length;
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            $td = $tr.eq(i).find('td');
            cur = parseInt( $td.eq(cols[2]).text(), 10); // current
            if (cur <= parseInt( $td.eq(cols[0]).text(), 10) || // min
                cur >= parseInt( $td.eq(cols[1]).text(), 10) ){ // max
                $td.eq(cols[2]).addClass('badqty');
            }
        }
    }
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    widgets : [ 'zebra', 'qty' ],
    widgetQty : [ 0, 1, 2 ] // min, max, current qty column indexes 
});​
```