# Change TD background color via condition >= or <= with between 2 number fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the <td> background if a field result is great or equal to another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760870/can-i-change-the-td-background-if-a-field-result-is-great-or-equal-to-another)

Trying to get my script to work, displaying mySQl results in an HTML table via php with a particular column TD that contains $qty that needs to have its background turn red when it equals or passes $min or $max.

Maybe there's a better way to right this php?

Script is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var min = parseInt($('.min').text());
var max = parseInt($('.max').text());
var qty = parseInt($('.quantity').text());

if (qty >= max || qty <= min ) {
$('.quantity').css('background-color', 'red');
} 
});
</script>
```

My php table / the three fields are toward the end of the table:

```
$o .= '<tr><td>'.$type.'</td><td>'.$part_no.'</td><td>'.$description.'</td><td>'.$artwork.' &nbsp; &nbsp;</td><td><a href="/data/hero/copies/'.$part_no.'.pdf" target="_blank">Link &nbsp;</a></td><td align=right class="min">'.number_format($min).'</td><td align=right class="max">'.number_format($max).'</td><td align=right class="quantity">'.number_format($qty).'</td></tr>';}
```

Comment: MAYBE that is not the way of adding css in a script, try this this is how i usually do mine: $('.quantity').css({backgroundColor: 'red'});

Comment: `$('.quantity').css('background-color', 'red');` is a perfectly valid way

Comment: @bPratik, that's why I answered MAYBE, implying there's another way.

Comment: Thank u gentlemen... very frustrating..  Could my class="quantity" in the TD in the table be written differently because I'm creating the table in php?

Comment: what do you mean by 'be written differently', you mean change the class name?

Comment: I'm confused on using the quotes and ''.  My align=right has none.  Not sure how to write it out.

Comment: in general, the proper quote to use is  " ", try it.

Comment: Actually the answer is progressing and I still need help with the script.  Thanks.

Comment: @CHiRiLo You _edited_ to include maybe while I was posting my comment. Having said that, that still doesn't change the fact that your answer is technically a non-answer. what you have pointed out is not the issue and I have felt it a better thing to point it out in a comment rather than _down-voting_ you. Also, you are seemingly wrong again since both single ('') and double ("") quotes are valid and can be nested to achieve the OP's result. Similar results can also be achieved by `escaping` each quote if similar types need nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php sample has a stray `}` at the end of the line. Is that causing this issue?

I've just tried this with the javascript you posted and this php:

```
$o = '<tr><td>'.$type.'</td><td>'.$part_no.'</td><td>'.$description.'</td><td>'.$artwork.' &nbsp; &nbsp;</td><td><a href="/data/hero/copies/'.$part_no.'.pdf" target="_blank">Link &nbsp;</a></td><td align=right class="min">'.number_format($min).'</td><td align=right class="max">'.number_format($max).'</td><td align=right class="quantity">'.number_format($qty).'</td></tr>';
```

It works perfectly.

Is `$o` getting properly printed out to the browser? If you view the HTML source, do you have a `td`s  with the classes min, max and quantity? What exact symptoms of it not working do you get? Maybe you could post a little more of the script?

Comment: Here is a link to the whole php script: http://jsfiddle.net/bdujU/   thank  for your help.

Comment: I just removed number_format and it worked but the condition is not working.

Comment: Do I need to add a else statement because all the results in the qty column are red?

Comment: I get this error: 
`Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`
Do you have jQuery as well as mootools loaded?

Comment: I've just stripped the PHP out of this and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/iHiD/bdujU/2/

Comment: Could you paste the HTML that the PHP generates, please?

Comment: JSFiddle does not work with PHP, but I thought I would show you the code.  I removed the number_format and the css style works but for all.  The condition is not working.

Comment: Does the conditioning in my fiddle work for you?